# AWS autoscaling. Launch Config/Auto Scaling Group and VPC instance with two ifaces

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, autoscaling

I want create an  Launch Config/Auto Scaling Group to build instances inside an VPC with two subnets ("frontend" and "backend")

I need these auto-scaled instances to have an interface in each of these two subnets.

I can't see how do that. It's not apparently possible from the AWS console and neither with the CLI.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/create-launch-configuration.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/create-auto-scaling-group.html

Launch Config doesn't say anything about this.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/create-lc-with-instanceID.html

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, right now it is not possible to assign multiple ENIs through auto-scaling, but only when launching single instances, but it is possible to [provision](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-CreateNetworkInterface.html) and [attach](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-AttachNetworkInterface.html) a new ENI on startup using the EC2 toolkits (not forgetting to set the dyamically added ENI to [delete on instance termination](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute.html)).

This is the same solution I used to implement autoscaled public instances with ElasticIPs before the automatic ElasticIP property existed.